# NodeJS Failing to load in credentials file AWS

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

This is what my code looks like:

```
'use strict';

process.env.AWS_PROFILE

// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Create EC2 service object
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

// Load credentials and set region from JSON file
AWS.config.loadFromPath('/Users/testuser/.aws/credentials');
// Load in security group parameters
const securityParams = require('./securityParams.json');

module.exports = {
    //Exports creation of Security Groups
    CreateSecurityGroup: (req, res) => {
        ec2.createSecurityGroup(securityParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return (console.log("Error", err));
            }
            // Pass the Json as a parameter in this function
            ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(securityParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.serverError(err, err.stack);
                } else {
                    res.ok(data);
                    console.log('Ingress Security Rules Created');
                }
            })
            // Pass the Json as a parameter in this function
            ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupEgress(securityParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.serverError(err, err.stack);
                } else {
                    res.ok(data);
                    console.log('Egress Security Rules Created');
                }
            })
        })
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to have the script load configurations from two files; one aws credentials file, and one json. However its throwing errors on the credentials file which looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=**************
aws_secret_access_key**************
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing to get it to read the properties in correctly.

Here is the error I'm seeing:

```
undefined:1
[default]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: *"However its throwing errors on the credentials file"* Two things: 1. ***What*** errors? 2. That's not JSON, but your title is *"NodeJS Failing to load in JSON"* (presumably `securityParams.json` contains JSON -- which you're treating as though it were JavaScript code via `require` -- but not the credentials).

Comment: Updated my question, so it sounds like I can't require the file the way I am trying to?

Comment: Looks like loadFromPath is trying to parse a JSON file, however the credentials file is not JSON. Here are two resources about setting credentials when using the AWS SDK. I personally prefer using environment variables. 

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-environment

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: One more question, in order to actually read in the JSON do I have to add in a JSON parse into my code? If so, where?

Answer (score 1):

credentials is a plain Ascii file, it's not json file

```
// Load credentials and set region from JSON file
AWS.config.loadFromPath('/Users/testuser/.aws/credentials');
```

You can check file type with command `file /Users/testuser/.aws/credentials`

sample snippet to read props file and set AWS config

```
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var properties = PropertiesReader('/Users/username/.aws/credentials');

AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId : properties.get('aws_access_key_id'),
        secretAccessKey : properties.get('aws_secret_access_key'),
        region : 'us-west-2'
})

console.log(AWS.config)
```

Ref:https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties-reader

Comment: Yes I recognize that now. Any idea how I can read those parameters into the script I'm writing, without changing the file as it is.

Comment: Yes, you have to use properties-reader package and update config accordingly.

Comment: Got it thats helpful. One more thing. Right now none of my functions in module exports are executing, basically nothing is being returned. Is there anything I need to do to get them to run?

Comment: No errors at all. Have tried two things, `AWS_PROFILE=aws-admin node AWS_Security_Group.js`

Comment: Just returns nothing.

Comment: You seems to miss calling function, add this line at end of your script
module.exports.CreateSecurityGroup(req,res)

Comment: So I get an error when I try and include that function. I thought putting the function inside of module exports exported it already? `module.exports.CreateSecurityGroup(req,res)
                                   ^

ReferenceError: req is not defined`

Comment: Yes it exports, but req,res objects are related to api calls so you have to call this function in that api. So if you want run this file independently, just remove references to all req,res and call module.exports.CreateSecurityGroup()

Comment: Got it thanks. One more question, in order to actually read in the JSON do I have to add in a JSON parse into my code? If so, where?